# SQL query. How to count the number of entries by month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a transaction table with 3 months data:

query:

```sql
SELECT a.branch,
       a.dt_acc,
       a.ct_id,
       TRUNC(a.date, 'MONTH'),
       COUNT(*) a_count
  FROM a_transactions a
 WHERE a.v_date BETWEEN '01.03.2019' and '31.05.2019'
 GROUP BY a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id, TRUNC(a.date, 'MONTH');
```

result:

| BRANCH | ACC | ID | TRUNC(A.DATE,'MONTH') | A_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 154 | 01.03.2019 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 154 | 01.04.2019 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 154 | 01.05.2019 | 1 |

For each month, a_count printed one record.
I need a_count to count the amount for previous months, that is, if in March a_count was equal to 1, in April there is also a record, a_count should already be 2, and if there is also a record in May, then a_count should be 3

I need this result:

| BRANCH | ACC | ID | TRUNC(A.DATE,'MONTH') | A_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 154 | 01.03.2019 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 154 | 01.04.2019 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 154 | 01.05.2019 | 3 |

Comment: You can use a window function to get a running total

Comment: do you have permission to create table on your db ?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe here is exactly sliding window functions. Syntax may vary a bit depending on your sql dialect, but generally you can use:

```
select a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id, trunc(a.date,'MONTH'), 
count(*) over (order by a.date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) a_count
from a_transactions a
where a.v_date between '01.03.2019' and '31.05.2019'
group by a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id, trunc(a.date,'MONTH');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cummulative sum like this:

```
WITH YOUR_SQL AS (
        SELECT A.BRANCH, A.DT_ACC, A.CT_ID, TRUNC(A.DATE,'MONTH') MM , COUNT(*) A_COUNT
FROM A_TRANSACTIONS A
WHERE A.V_DATE BETWEEN '01.03.2019' AND '31.05.2019'
GROUP BY A.BRANCH, A.DT_ACC, A.CT_ID, TRUNC(A.DATE,'MONTH')
    )
SELECT Y.* , SUM (A_COUNT) OVER (ORDER BY MM,BRANCH,DT_ACC,CT_ID) CUM_SUM
FROM YOUR_SQL Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use(without neding a subquery) `SUM(COUNT()) OVER ()` as an analytic function such as

```sql
SELECT branch,
       dt_acc,
       ct_id,
       TO_CHAR("date", 'yyyy') AS year,
       TRUNC("date", 'MONTH') AS first_day_of_month,
       COUNT(*) AS a_count,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR("date", 'yyyy') 
            ORDER BY TRUNC("date", 'MONTH')) AS a_count_sum
  FROM a_transactions
 WHERE v_date BETWEEN date'2019-03-01' and date'2019-05-31'
 GROUP BY branch, dt_acc, ct_id, TO_CHAR("date", 'yyyy'), TRUNC("date", 'MONTH')
```

where

- using `date'yyyy-mm-dd'` format is a good habit in order to prevent
  date literal issues independent of what the date settings for the DB
- `date` is a reserved word and cannot be used as column name unless quoted(*eg.your column presumed to be `"date"`*)
- considering the other years would also be a good idea. Perhaps your
  upcoming data will propagate for more than one year(*eg.the interval of dates might be extended to cover more than one year*).